# Send multiple "println" to the client

Tags: java

I need to send to the client some infomartion.

In this example I send what inside the `println` 2 times, but the client reads only the first time.
How can the client read all the data that sent to him?

At client side i tried to use multiple `readline`, inside a for loop...doesn't work.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    int apart = i+1;    
    String response2 = getDataConnection(clientRes, apart);
    pr.println("aparment " + apart +"  "  + response2);
    pr.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must flush outside of the loop

```java
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {                     
    int apart = i+1;    
    String response2 = getDataConnection(clientRes, apart);
    pr.println("aparment " + apart +"  "  + response2);
}
pr.flush();
```

While you `print` you actually write in your Buffer
And when you `flush`, you send the buffer content to the client